# When is the bipod used and can this be controlled?

Tags: battlefield-3

Sometimes, either prone or crouched, my player will fold down the bipod, forcing the gun to move slightly and blinding my scope with leaves in the process.

I've unlocked the bipod on a number of weapons (SAW, SV98, M4) and I was wondering what triggers it to be used in the game?

Comment: I personally prefer not to use the bipod, it significantly slows me down, I can miss a chance to shoot while setting it up. Shift works fine on all sniper rifles, but LMG and assault rifles - almost all of them have a "semi-auto" firing mode, which is precise enough to hit the target on almost any range. However, SAW, for example, doesn't have one, so I use it only in hot battles on small maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just in: looks like the bipod will be controllable through a distinct key in future PC patches:

https://twitter.com/#!/Demize99/status/154876865859960833

> The bipod deploy button separate and bindable on PC should make a future update.

Doubtful this will make it to consoles since the controllers are already bound to the max with functions.

Answer (score 0):

The bipod is *supposed* to be extended automatically when you either go prone on flat, or moderately flat terrain, or crouch next to something with a flat surface such as a jersey barrier. Basically, if there's a surface for your bipod to rest on, your character's going to take the extra time to take it out.

However there is currently a bug in the game that will prevent the bipod from deploying when aiming down the sights; sometimes requiring two or three additional attempts.

Comment: It's a bit clunky, though. Sometimes you'll need to re-aim to force it out.

Comment: @Yatrix I haven't played it in about a month... I was assuming they'd fixed that by now.

Comment: Unless it's been fixed in the last week or so, it hasn't.

Comment: Indeed it hasn't, and that was the point of my question.

Comment: If I recall correctly I don't remember a single instance of the bipod *correctly* deploying on the first aim attempt. I always have to re-do it. I basically just double-tap aim every time i want to use the bipod now.

Answer (score 0):

I find this annoying too. When I go into zoom (scope) mode and the bipod is deployed and I would rather use the weapon bipod-less, I quickly hit either the `left` or `right` cursor key; that folds the bipod away while staying zoomed in.

Answer (score 0):

It automatically sets up the bi-pod when on a raised surface or when prone and aim down sight for a couple of seconds. It helps with stability but can also slow you down, but is good for camping or defending an objective. 
If you simply don't like it, then don't use it.

http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Deployable_Bipod

Comment: How's your answer better than Tristan's?